# Dynamically calculate data between points

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm creating a chart with 2 series. The series share the same axis but have different Ys for different Xs. For example:

- Axis A: `[{ x: 2, y: 5}, { x: 4, y: 10}]`
- Axis B: `[{ x: 1, y: 2}, { x: 3, y: 6}, { x: 3, y: 9}]`

I want to show a tooltip for each X value that appears in axis A (so in this case, for x = 2, 4) and in the tooltip show the value that both axis would have there.

So the problem is that for axis B I don't have a point for x = 2 and x = 4. Is there a way to calculate dinamically the Y value that the axis B would have in those Xs?

This is an example: the tooltip shows info of the blue point, but also calculates what the corresponding green point would be and shows it in the tooltip.
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I prepared the demo version [https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h6e8c0La/](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h6e8c0La/) are you looking for something like this? There are two series at the different yAxis and they have data with points.

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I meant. In my case, the first series has some point, the second has other, and when we over on each point it shows the tooltip for that point. I would like that the tooltip would not only show the info of that point, but also calculate the value of the corresponding point on the other series and show it. Is it possible? (I attached an image to my original post)

Comment: Options that allow shared tooltip to series is **tooltip.shared** [https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared). [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true-mixed-types/)